# Groupby and find top 10% of records per group in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a new DataFrame containing the top 10% of count records per group.

An example of initial df is as follows;

```
date        name       count
2014-12-14  Jerry      1
2014-12-21  Jerry      2
2015-01-11  Jerry      3
2015-02-01  Jerry      4
2015-02-08  Jerry      5
2015-03-01  Jerry      6
2015-03-08  Jerry      7
2015-03-15  Jerry      8
2015-03-22  Jerry      9
2015-04-26  Jerry      10
2014-12-14  Tom        1
2014-12-21  Tom        2
2015-01-11  Tom        3
2015-02-01  Tom        4
2015-02-08  Tom        5
2015-03-01  Tom        6
2015-03-08  Tom        7
2015-03-15  Tom        8
2015-03-22  Tom        9
2015-04-26  Tom        10
```

The above DataFrame is simply a snippet of the full DataFrame which contains numerous names, and contains weekly `count` information per name over a year period.

The required output I would like is as follows.

```
date        name       count
2015-04-26  Jerry      10
2015-04-26  Tom        10
```

I would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom lambda function for get `10%` by rows per groups:

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(['name','count'], ascending=[True, False])
         .groupby('name', group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.head(int(len(x) / 10))))
print (df1)
          date   name  count
9   2015-04-26  Jerry     10
19  2015-04-26    Tom     10
```

Comment: @jerzrael Thanks very much that worked a charm. To get the bottom `10%` would I simply change `x.head` to `x.tail`?

Comment: @moe_95 - yes, exactly.